# Lifelog API Explorer: Authorization request could not be completed

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I'd like to use the lifelog api for my own webapplication to store my own data and adapt it to my needs. I tried looking into it but unfortunately I'm not able to get the api explorer (to see how it works) to work. When I try to use the Authenthication OAuth2 and log in to my google account it constantly gives me the following error:

> Authorization request could not be completed. Reason: Access token
>   request to API provider failed.
>
> If the problem persists, please contact Customer Support.

Unfortunately I don't have much experience with REST based services and I've searched for an answer here but didn't find anything to get started. I use the latest version of Google Chrome and have also tried Edge (I'm not wondering why it wouldnt work there). Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the API Explorer is not working correctly right now. The team is working to fix the issue. In the meantime you can try postman to play around with the API.

https://www.getpostman.com/

Here is one way to make it happen:

1. Setup a get request to: https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/v1/users/me
2. Under "Authorization" click "Get Access Token".
3. Here you will see a callback URL. Go in to your Lifelog API Management and register an application with the provided callback: https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/create-app/
4. Once done add the client id and secret provided from your API Management console in to Postman and click "Get Access Token"
5. You will be provided with an access token. Give this a name and click save.
6. Now click on Headers and add "Authorization" as the "URL Parameter Key" and "Bearer ##Enter your access token here##" as the "Value"
7. At this point click send and you should receive results from the API.

Let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Hello, I was following this steps, and I'm always getting 401 Unauthorized all the time. I'm using another REST client. I can get the Code and the Token, but when I want to get the activities I can't get any.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was putting the Header incorrectly. It should be   Authorization: Bearer HERE_THE_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I got information about my profile but not about my activities... I added the scopes the following way before getting the access code:
lifelog.profile.read lifelog.activities.read lifelog.locations.read
did I do something wrong?

Comment: I now realized that I didn't use the correct URL for the activities (just add /activities) - thanks for the help!

Comment: ok great!! Glad to hear that things are working. Please let me know if you need more assistance