# Can I access Lifelog APIs from my android application

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

When ever I tried to authorize my android application. But It gives me Unauthorized user error..

Can i access lifelog data on my android application using these lifelog REST API's?

could some one suggest me the steps to configure my android app to read data from lifelog  API's

Answer (score 0):

What steps have you tried to retrieve data from the API? Are you following the instructions from the Lifelog Authorization page?

https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/authentication/

Some quick things you can do are:

1. Be sure that there are no spaces in your client id
2. Try creating a new client id and secret to be sure that there is nothing wrong with your current credentials
3. Try using Postman as a quick way to verify that there is not something else causing the issue. For instance something network related. Here is a link to a quick explanation on how to get going: [Lifelog API Explorer: Authorization request could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383119/lifelog-api-explorer-authorization-request-could-not-be-completed/34391740#34391740)

Comment: I tried using the postman.. whats the Authorization URL and Access Token URl ? I have my client ID and Client Secret

Comment: With out this authorization URL and Token URL it says "Could not complete Auth2.0 login

Comment: This is the Error we are getting when we are trying to get the access token from ANDROID application.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591928/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate-error-in-lifelogapi

Comment: If you are creating an android app the problem may be with your use of HttpClient. It looks like Google has removed support for this call in Android 6.0. You can see the full answer at the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

the LifeLog API is a RESTful API, meaning, you can, in theory, access it from anywhere as long as you can create `HTTP` requests. 
The authentication used is standard `Oauth2` which also is defacto used by most APIs like Google, Facebook, Twitter etc.

Other than that, there are a couple of Android libraries available which can make your life a lot easier, wrapping the HTTP requests into simple Java objects and methods.

https://github.com/championswimmer/Lifelog-Android-Library

https://github.com/yaeda/lifelog-android-sdk

*Disclaimer: The first library linked has been co-authored by me*