# Android App - SSL Unverified Error while getting Access Token from lifelog

Tags: ssl-certificate, sony, android-developer-api, sony-lifelog-api

I am getting ssl peer unverified error while fetching AccessToken from lifelog api. 
If I use Nexus phone I am able to get access token and the data from life log aswell
But same doesnt work on any other android phone (including sony xperia)

This is what I did
1) I am able to get the auth_code from the callback URL
2) Now, I am trying to get Access_Token and it is giving me SSL peer Unverified exception.

I compared all the installed trusted credential but didn't find any suspicious certificate
Any solution to resolve?

Comment: As I mentioned in another Post the problem may be with using HttpClient to connect to the API. Have a look at my response to a similar problem and let me know if this fixes the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591928/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate-error-in-lifelogapi/34820336#34820336

Comment: could you post a sample of your code and the exact Exception that's being thrown? I'm using ```google-oauth-java-client```, and I might be able to help you if I can see some snippets